# Return value for function that there is a callback function inside

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I write a function to check does an item exist in list that was stored in storage. Everything is ok, just problem to return value for function. Here is my code:

```
function isExistInWhitelist(s){
    var res = false;
    chrome.storage.local.get("whitelist", function(result){
        for(var i = 0; i< result.whitelist.length; i++)
            if(result.whitelist[i].indexOf(s)>=0){
                res = true;//[1]
                break;
            };
    });
    return res;
}
```

When I use console.log to write res value in [1], result is ok (true), but I cannot return value for isExistInWhitelist function. What need I do?

Comment: I don't this your suggest content is same my problem. My problem didn't relate to ajax!!!!!

Comment: It doesn't relate to ajax but it is still an asynchronous call. So you require the same solution.